# Natural Language Parsing for ToDo application

Tags: language-agnostic, parsing

I'm wondering if someone could lead me to any examples of natural language parsing for to do lists.  Nothing as intense as real Natural Language Parsing, but something that could process the line:

> Go to George's house at 3pm on Tuesday with Kramer

as well as the line:

> 3 on tuesday go to georges

and get the same output.

I've seen other to do applications that do this sort of work in the past.  Is there anything out there with examples or have people just custom written this code themselves?

Comment: That'll be hard because everyone knows Tuesday doesn't have a feeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody pointed out this natural language parsing on this site..kudos to whoever you are for posting the link...http://code.gustavonarea.net/booleano/

Answer (score 0):

That's a great idea!  As you might imagine this is vastly complex and can be approached in many different ways.  Perhaps check out the Natural Language Toolkit for starters, which is mostly python but also requires building some Ocaml and Java components.  I also recommend reading some books and or papers on lexical semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something similar to this in Perl. The input would be a day/time with the name of some action. Sentences like: "3pm Run full unit test suite", "reboot servers on dec 25", etc.

I used the Perl module [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-5.54/lib/Date/Manip.pod) since it's awesome for this sort of thing and coded the rest of the logic manually.

Comment: Care to share your code as an example for those of us who want to learn?

Comment: I'd love to, but it was for a past employer :|